# Is there an OpenID library for python which supports UI extensions?

Tags: python, openid

I'm using the python openid library available here:

https://github.com/openid/python-openid

I would like to use the UI extensions to OpenID to
ensure that the authentication process is performed via
a popup rather than redirection to the provider's site.

However, the above library does not seem to have support
for the extensions built in - has anyone added support
for the UI extensions to this library?

Comment: python-openid is the only well-maintained library I know of. It has nice capability for extensions though. You could always contribute and [add support for UI extensions](https://github.com/openid/python-openid/tree/master/openid/extensions).

Comment: I'll put it on my todo list - thanks!